# How can I start over?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

Is there a way to completely start the game over?  Some things in the game are altered between runs and are permanently changed.  For example, there is a broom closet in the left hallway that has interesting dialogue.  If you enter it a second time on another play-through, you get more dialogue.  From then on, the room is boarded up and cannot be entered.

Is there a was to start clean without reinstalling the game or anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you completely close out the game and then open it again, you get the "clean start" that you are looking for, with the broom closet unboarded.

**Things This Will Reset**

- The Broom Closet
- The "Break Room" commmentary
- The Boss's Office, including accessibility to the washroom and elevator, as well as the door-opening setting.
- The initial rooms (though any random setup can occur after the first "standard" start)
- Your visual orientation at the start (if you get an ending or restart, you will always be facing out the door, but at the very start, you are facing your monitor)
- The "Serious Room" dialogue.
- The "Employee Of the Month" picture.

Answer (score 3):

Two things of interest to get a cleaner start.

First, the save files are, [according to this gamefaq thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/727960-the-stanley-parable/67553012) in

> ...saves are located in your steamlibrary
>   \SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\The Stanley Parable\thestanleyparable\save
>   then the subdirectory you ll find there.

Deleting them will make sure nothing from previous saves might be used.

Second, this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FYd5D049gM) shows that you can reset your achievement progress with

> Use the console command "tsp_resetzaxis" to reset your achievement progress

so that you can do them again.

Comment: I'm curious: What does deleting your save file reset?

Comment: When you got a save file, the game will use it to change the current run. It might not be necessary to delete it but I feel it is better if you really want a "fresh" start.

Comment: It is not necessary.  I can't think of anything that is affected by the save file when starting the game from the beginning simply by reloading the game.